# How do I flatten and collecting an Iterator of futures to results?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future

When manipulating a Vector of Futures, I end up with a nested Vector of Vectors, which I then need to flatten in two iterations.

Dummy code for illustrative purposes:

```
use std::error::Error;
use futures::future::join_all;
  
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    async fn duplicate(number: i32) -> Result<Vec<i32>, Box<dyn Error>> {
        Ok(vec!(number * 2))
    }

    let my_numbers = vec!(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    let future_duplicated_evens = my_numbers.into_iter().filter_map(|number| {
            if number % 2 == 0 {
            Some(duplicate(number))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let flattened = join_all(future_duplicated_evens).await.into_iter().collect::<Result<Vec<_>, Box<dyn Error>>>().unwrap().into_iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<i32>>();
    
    println!("Flattened: {:?}", flattened);
}
```

Link to the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=53647e52766d10fd45bce408c8a6f666).

In the sample code above, for `flattened` I first need to collect the Vector of Results from the joined Futures into a Result of a Vec, and after that I need to iterate again just to flatten the Vectors.

My question is, is there a way to collect and flatten in a single iteration?

Comment: well, you could just skip the collect on `future_duplicated_evens` and return an iterator.

Comment: Seems that skipping the collection on `future_duplicated_evens` does not make a difference, since `join_all` will return a Vec anyway:

```
impl<F> Future for JoinAll<F>
where
    F: Future,
{
    type Output = Vec<F::Output>;
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal example that compiles/runs? That would make it much easier to experiment with it in the playground and is likely to attract more answerers.

Comment: Sure! I will edit the dummy code example for it to compile

Comment: The reproducible code and the playground have been added now :).

Answer (score 0):

Since in your example you don't care about handling the errors cleanly, you can simply apply `Result::unwrap` to each element using `map` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=559f3b181a702af5973ad94c0483bb13)):

```
let flattened = join_all(future_duplicated_evens)
    .await
    .into_iter()
    .map(Result::unwrap)
    .flatten()
    .collect::<Vec<i32>>();
```

If in your real code you do care about handling errors, you can use `try_fold` instead which will accumulate all of values in a single vector but abort if it comes across an error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cafde04dbcbbecbda5e664adcdabd920)):

```
let flattened = join_all(future_duplicated_evens)
    .await
    .into_iter()
    .try_fold(Vec::new(), |mut acc, next| {
        acc.extend_from_slice(&next?);
        Ok::<Vec<i32>, Box<dyn Error>>(acc)
    })
    .unwrap();
```

Comment: Thanks, @apilar! Yeah, I used unwrap just for the sake of making the dummy code compile